# Saving variable references to workbooks using ActiveWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a permanent reference to two specific workbooks, but when looking at the locals window, they do not

I've tried referencing ThisWorkbook.Name as well, but it does not seem to solve the issue. It always seem to go back to referencing Workbook/ThisWorkbook.

```
Sub Import_data()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sFound As String, WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook

Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook

sFound = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\*Name.xlsx")    'the first one found
If sFound <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & sFound
    Set WB2 = ActiveWorkbook
End If

WB2.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Copy _
WB1.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K18")


End Sub
```

I get the subscript out of range error when I run the sub.

Comment: Try the code in the answer. You have allocated the WB2 the wrong way and you should put copy paste code inside the If Condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
Sub Import_data()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sFound As String, WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook

Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook

sFound = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*Name.xlsx")    'the first one found

If sFound <> "" Then

    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFound)
    WB2.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Copy
    WB1.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If



End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code, but both WB1 and WB2 still point to the same workbook under locals window and i'm still getting the subscript out of range error.

Comment: Actually, my bad. My sheet references were invalid. Pointed to the right sheets and its fixed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & sFound
Set WB2 = ActiveWorkbook
```

to

```
Set WB2=Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & sFound)
```

Comment: Problem is in Range too, as no matter sfound is true or False, Copy Paste code is running. It should be inside If Condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a clean code : never use `ActiveWorkbook` !

Try this :

```
Sub Import_data()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sFound As String, WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook

Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook

sFound = Dir(WB1.path & "\*Name.xlsx")    'the first one found

If sFound <> "" Then
    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=WB1.path & "\" & sFound)
    WB2.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Copy _
    WB1.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K18")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try your code in the Editor Window, you will know there is still some redness in it !

Comment: Yes, I just missed the `()`, I edited my answer. Thanks